# Simulate a denied payment (lack of funds)

Tags: paypal, sandbox

Using paypal sandbox account.

I can successfully test a payment "completed" but i don't know how to simulate a refused (lack of funds) transaction because the credit card created with sandbox buyer profile  has unlimited funds....

I know IPN simulator but what i need is to see the buyer's "experience" in case of lack of funds.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use negative testing while testing in the Sandbox to trigger a decline.  You can find more on negative testing [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ug_sandbox).

Comment: Tried it and the personal account magically gets enough money to pay for what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a paypal PERSONAL sandbox  account and give 0$ funds to that account.
And pay from your PERSONAL sandbox account to your BUSSINESS sandbox account.
I think you need at least two sandbox accounts to simulate a payment.

Look for more info on:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/ipn-test-outside

Comment: I tried that myself and it didn't work for some reason...the payment was still successful.